# How can we can get created date of first created in parent record using workflow

Tags: workflow

I am trying to write a workflow to update a field on account with created date of first contact record. Unfortunately couldn't see contact fields in the workflow formula editor. Is there any alternate for this using configuration? Any idea is greatly appreciated. Expecting an idea on how to get this value, so that i can write the logic accordingly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update Child record from parent record using Workflow rule.For this you will need to use process builder which allow to update child record from parents and vice versa.

Go thorough below  links which has other alternative to update child record from parent record using configuration.

[Auto updating child records in Process Builder](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/auto-updating-child-records-process-builder)

Hope this helps :)